# How to toast clicked item name in new open activity

Tags: android, listview, listitem

When I click on List item then I want to open a new activity and display the item name was clicked. I tried much, but clicked item name isn't toast, a new activity open but not display item name, how I fetched clicked item name in new open activity? So how do I do that?

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String strName = listitem.get(arg2).getOppid();

        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, strName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

it toast item name in same activity successfully but I want also display item name in new activity.

I want toast clicked item name in that second activity I tried this way but fail to get solve.

```
public class Second_activity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Services>listitem;
    String title,name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_activity);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        name= i.getStringExtra("name");
        Toast.makeText(Second_activity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: You aren't not saving the string into the Intent. You have to do something like `intent.putExtra("item-name", strName);`

Comment: pls write me some code i am not understand. @Robert

Comment: Check all the answers. In every answer this piece of code has been added. You need to save the string name if you want to request this string later. You cannot do this in your second activity: `i.getStringExtra("name");`  if you didn't set this your first: `intent.putExtra("name", strName);`

Comment: where i can write this code intent.putExtra("name", strName); in which line ? pls help me @Robert

Comment: After the Intent creation and before the start activity. You have to setting up the Intent extras in order to request the extra in the second activity.

Comment: I didn't understand  `why this silly question has 9-10 answer?` Might be android devs are free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modified Your Code**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     String strName = listitem.get(arg2).getOppid();

                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, strName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second_activity.class);
          //add below line to take clicked item to next activity
          intent.putExtra("ITEMCLICKED",strName);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

**Add Below code In Second acticity onCreate method**

```
  String mClickedItem;
//get the inten from the previous activity
Intent intent=getIntent();
//intent.hasExtra("ITEMCLICKED") to check intent has the value which we have set in previous activity
if(intent.hasExtra("ITEMCLICKED")){
mClickedItem = intent.getStringExtra("ITEMCLICKED");
 }
 Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, mClickedItem,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send the string via Intent (`intent.putExtra()`), or via [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), or put it in the SharedPreferences. Choose whichever you like.

- Intent will do nicely if you do not need any complex data sent, just
  a simple `string`, `int` or something.
- SharedPreferences make sense    if you need to access that data when
  you next visit your app, meaning    that the data should be saved.
- Use EventBus if you wish to send your    own custom objects which can
  contain variety of data stored in them.

Comment: @saim you should check this answer. It is a good answer even with other option.

Comment: Thanks, @Robert. Those are all the ways I know how to do this, all the logical ones at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: i want toast in second activity not same activity, it works fine in same activity but not work in second, i posted some part of relevant code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Put name into extras and pass it to new activity. In new activity get name from extras and show.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code 

`Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second_activity.class);
intent.putStringExtra("name",strName);`

Answer (score 0):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String strName = listitem.get(arg2).getName();

        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, strName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second_activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("string", strName);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

### your second activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_activity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name= intent.getExtras().getString("string");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String strName = listitem.get(arg2).getOppid();

bundle.putString("msg", strName);
Intent intent =newIntent(getApplicationContext(),Second_activity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

and then in secondActivity's onCreate

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take at look at this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String strName = listitem.get(arg2).getOppid();

        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, strName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second_activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", strName);//add this line
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is your code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String strName = listitem.get(arg2).getOppid();

        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, strName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second_activity.class);
            // you need to set the string here
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

So, you have to set this on your first activity:

```
intent.putExtra("item-name", strName);
```

And in your second Activity:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String name = intent.getExtras().getString("item-name");
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Also I recommend you check your extra before:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras  = intent.getExtras();
if(extras.containsKey("item-name")){
    //asking for your key and do something with it
}
```